# Get the highest String Version number in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the highest version of a string in Python. I was trying to sort the list but that of course doesnt work as easily as Python will sort the string representation.

For that I am trying to work with regex but it somehow doesnt match.

The Strings look like this:

```
topic_v10_ext2
topic_v20_ext2
topic_v2_ext2
topic_v5_ext2
topic_v7_ext2
```

My Regex looks like this.

```
version_no = re.search("(?:_v([0-9]+))?", v.name)
```

I was thinking about saving the names in a list and look for the highest v_xx in the list to return.
Also for now I am doing this in two FOR loops. Which runs in 2*O(log(n)) which is not optimal I believe.
How can I get the highest version in a fast and simple way?

Comment: Please show the exact data format of the input strings. Are they in a file, a list, or some other data structure? Is the value after `ext` part of the version number?

Comment: What is meant by "string representation"? Why can't the `topic_v…` be strings?

Comment: Your regex will match literally anywhere because you've made the entire thing optional with the `?` at the end.

Comment: @RoryDaulton no, only the _vXX is part of the Version. But the ext is optional and not always present.

Comment: @PrinceOfCreation They are a different Object which has a .name Key which can be read as a String in a for loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sorted` or `list.sort` with `key`:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x:int(x.split('_')[1][1:]), reverse=True)
['topic_v20_ext2',
 'topic_v10_ext2',
 'topic_v7_ext2',
 'topic_v5_ext2',
 'topic_v2_ext2']
```

- `x.split('_')`: returns splitted `str`, e.g.: `['topic', 'v20', 'ext2']`
- Since the version is the key to the sorting, select it by `x.split('_')[1]`
- Selected `V20` has unwanted character 'V', thus reselect it by slicing `[1:]` to get all the digits.
- Finally, convert digits to `int` for numerical ordering.

Also, `sorted` by default returns ascending order of sort. Since you require descending order, use `reverse=True`.

Comment: Though mind explaining the x:int(x.split('_')[1][1:] part a bit once you have the time?

Comment: @DerekHaynes I've edited the answer. Please let me know if any part is unclear.

Comment: Yeah man! Best man of the day! This explained it really clear for me and for many to come. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there also a way to look for a regex inside the split like:
int(x.name.split('_')[1] "Regex to start and end at the number").
The version should be in the format of "v_00" but maybe something arrives like "version_00"

Comment: @DerekHaynes That can be a completely different scenario since it contains `_` and thus split may not work. If you were to extract digits, you can use `lambda x: re.findall('\d+', x)[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

It could also work with regular expressions, as first tried:

```
import re
v = 'topic_v7_ext2'
version_no = re.search("^[^_]*_v([0-9]+)", v)
print(version_no.group(1))
```

That expression searches for pattern from the beginning of the string (^), takes all characters different from _ (I hope your topics can't have one, else both answers are wrong), then finds the '_v' and takes the version number.
There is no need to match _ext, so it doesn't matter if it's there or not!